# JavaScript function that returns an object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

This function is supposed to return an object, however, the construction used below is unfamiliar to me. How does this function work?

```
function expect(value) {
  return {
    toBe: exp => console.log(success)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular part of this code that you don't understand? You seem to understand that it is returning an object already (which is what the `{}` is after the `return`)?

Comment: What are you confused about exactly?  It is definitely weird, in that `value` is never used, but the gist is: call `expect()` and the return is an object with a single property: `toBe`, which is another function that ignores what it is passed and simply logs "success" to the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard JavaScript function:

```
function(parameter1, parameter2) {
    return returnVal;
}
```

But the object that is being returned looks like this:

```
{
    toBe: exp => console.log(success)
}
```

Which is an object containing an ES6 arrow function, and can be alternatively expressed like so (a direct translation to an ES5 function):

```
{
    toBe: function(exp) { 
        return console.log(success);
    }
}
```

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more information on ES6 arrow function notation.

Comment: a more accurate es5 representation would be `return console.log(success)`. why did you add an explicit `return undefined` when the es6 isn't doing that?

Comment: My bad, got mixed up @Mulan (although it is functionally identical, only syntactically different).

Answer (score 0):

I think it worth emphasizing that returns an object with a key that contains a function as a value. You can run it in the same way to run a method belonging to a class. Obliviously it fails because there is no success defined.

```js
function expect(value) {
  return {
    toBe: exp => console.log(success)
  }
}

let res = expect('value')
console.log(res)
res.toBe('test')
```

I would say that this is the intent of the code, imo this makes a lot of sense; the evaluation is done when toBe is invoked, this invokes console.log(which tests the condition, when is invoked and prints the result):

```js
function expect(value) {
  return {
    toBe: exp => console.log(exp === value)
  }
}

expect('value').toBe('value')
expect('notvalue').toBe('value')
```